# caching images in webview android

Tags: php, android, caching, webview

i've got a webview application and i want to remove the images caching on it.
i try to put that "?123456789" after every image, to break the caching , but it doesn't work.
can you help me please?

```
if($passed[$i] == 1) {echo "<div class=\"contenitoreeventi\">
           <form method='get' action='paginaevento.php'>
          <input type='submit' 
          style='background-image: url(../fotoluoghi/$foto[$i].png?12345689);' 
          class='fotoevento' 
          name='idfesta' 
          value='$idfesta[$i]'/>
           </form>
            ";
```

Comment: Now the image.png?123456789 will be cached... You need different names EVERY TIME, like image.png?1, image.png?2, etc. if you want to stop caching.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add something that will change for every request of the image, something like a timestamp. Just using ?123456689 won't stop the caching if it results in the same URL for subsequent calls.

I usually use a timestamp formatted as:  "yyyyMMddHHmmss"